# Space between keyboard and EditText in Android

Tags: java, android, keyboard

Soft input mode is `"SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN"`, and when keyboard shown, `EditText` moves up to stay visible, but the keyboard and txt's bottom are always sticked together as seen on screenshot, I want some space between them, is it possible?

Also input mode must stay as `"SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN"`.

Sorry form my english, Thanks in Advance...

[image: Screenshot:]

Comment: Why insisting on using "adjustPan"?
Using "adjustResize" wil not have that issue.

Comment: Cuz when using "adjustResize", the biggest problem is navigation bar at bottom is shifting to top of the keyboard.

Answer (score 5):

I applied above methods which worked for me was 
Set android:windowSoftInputMode on the Activity to "adjustPan"
than i added the padding to the edittext with gravity bottom
and it works like charm.
Thanks,

Comment: Padding is what works, because unlike margins it is seen by the window manager as internal to the view. For example: editText.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 40) will cause your view to get an additional 40px of space beneath it when the keyboard appears. I did not have to set the gravity for this to work.

Comment: what happens to the text inside the edittext if you do this?

Comment: @user1232726 if you set the height of the edit text to wrap_content, then your text would appear off-center but it would all be visible. Different story if, for example, you set the edit text height to 41dp and paddingBottom to 40dp

Comment: When I add padding it pushes the line under the EditText down as well, messing up the design. I, therefore, don't think this is the best solution

Answer (score 4):

May this help you:

If this line is written in your code then remove it:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

**OR:**

You should not be setting your `layout_width` and `layout_heights` with explicit pixel values. Instead, use `wrap_parent` or `fill_parent` as appropriate.

**OR:**

If you have set your `minSdkVersion` to `3` then change it to `minSdkVersion=4`

**Edit:**

Set [android:windowSoftInputMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) on the Activity to `"adjustPan"`

**OR:**

Add this code in your main activity in `setOnTouchListener()` of your `EditText`:

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_UNSPECIFIED);
```

Comment: Thank you, input mode must stay SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN. When keyboard shown it sticks to edittexts(for example edittext at bottom of screen). It is ok but I want some space between edittext and keyboard.

Comment: Welcome buddy.. what i have done till now suggested you.. and try after adding `marginBottom Attribute` in EditText in `xml` and if any of these suggestion worked for you then please tick this answer..

Comment: @altosh: Buddy if my answer helped you then pls tick it so that other may know that it is correct answer...

Answer (score 1):

You can add drawable to edit text like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="30dp" />
            <padding
                android:bottom="10dp"
                android:left="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:top="10dp" />
        </shape>

    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/primary" />
            <corners android:radius="30dp" />
        </shape>

    </item>
</layer-list>
```

[image]

add below line in your activity or fragment:

```
requireActivity().getWindow()
          .setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

and in Manifest file:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan"
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this?

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

I know you want to adjust pan but this would solve your problem aswell.

Since you really want to stay with adjustPan, maybe you can try re-designing the XML layout a little bit.

You must also add your required padding to the outer most container element in the layout file.

Comment: no space between edittext and soft keyboard. cant figure it out

Comment: @filthy_wizard check the padding in your layout

Comment: i have a doubt this works for me but im using bottom navigation and this one ups to with the keyboard so the space is huge and you can see and press any navigation button

Answer (score 0):

Simple padding in edit text won't work.

Use drawable with your edit text like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:bottom="8dp"
        android:left="8dp"
        android:right="8dp"
        android:top="8dp">

        <shape android:shape="rectangle">

            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/white" />
            <solid android:color="@color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and then use

```
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

in your manifest file.

Answer (score -1):

Just wondering, is your app full screen? does it have the status bar? If it is try to disable full screen mode and try to see if that solves your problem. I remember there was a bug about this some time ago.

Answer (score -1):

try to [use](https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2016/keyboard-handling-on-android/) GlobalLayoutListener:

private var focusView:View?=null

```
// Register global layout listener.
    decorView?.viewTreeObserver?.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {

        private val windowVisibleDisplayFrame = Rect()
        private var lastVisibleDecorViewHeight: Int = 0

        override fun onGlobalLayout() {

            // Retrieve visible rectangle inside window.
            decorView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(windowVisibleDisplayFrame)
            val visibleDecorViewHeight = windowVisibleDisplayFrame.height()

            // Decide whether keyboard is visible from changing decor view height.
            if (lastVisibleDecorViewHeight != 0) {
                if (lastVisibleDecorViewHeight > visibleDecorViewHeight + MIN_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT_PX) {
                    // Calculate current keyboard height (this includes also navigation bar height when in fullscreen mode).
                    val currentKeyboardHeight = decorView.height - windowVisibleDisplayFrame.bottom

        //keyboardHeight = currentKeyboardHeight


          focusView =  activity?.currentFocus     
          focusView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, SET_BOTTOM_PADDING_SPACE)  // <---set space here



                } else if (lastVisibleDecorViewHeight + MIN_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT_PX < visibleDecorViewHeight) {

                    focusView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0)

                }
            }
            // Save current decor view height for the next call.
            lastVisibleDecorViewHeight = visibleDecorViewHeight
        }
    })
```