# How to add margin between EditText and Soft Keyboard?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-edittext, android-keypad

I want to add 10dp margin between EditText and Soft Keyboard.

[image]
Here is my XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/BottomLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/bottom_glass" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/grey"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:hint="Enter Message"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" >


    </EditText>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/sendMessageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/message"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/sendselector" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/message"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/sendmediaselector" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my `onCreate()` :

```
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
    messageText.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                            ((Swipe)getActivity()).getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_UNSPECIFIED);
                    return false;
                }});
```

I am using viewpager and full screen theme. The following EditText is in my 3rd fragment.

I've used `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan"` and `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`, but nothing happened.

Comment: Have you tried changing the EditText's padding?

Comment: No i want it in center of layout

Comment: i am new to android so doesn't know what is better.

Comment: try `android:layout_gravity="center"`

Comment: padding increases the height of edit text but i want space between edittext and keyboard. also i am using relative layout it will great if keyboard does not hide that. it hides the half relative layout

Comment: @Punit did you resolved your problem??

Comment: @Riddhish.Chaudhari Not Yet Mate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Space between keyboard and EditText in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17630336/space-between-keyboard-and-edittext-in-android)

Answer (score 23):

I find the attribute of `paddingBottom` can effect the distance between the `editText` and the keyboard. You can do like this:

```
<RelativeLayout   
  android:layout_width="match_parent"   
  android:layout_height="110dp"> 
  <ImageView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="100dp"
     android:background="@drawable/your_edit_text_background"/>   
  <EditText
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:paddingBottom="10dp"/> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

This will make your keyboard margin your `EditText` by `10dp`

Comment: android:paddingBottom="5dp" , not padding_bottom

Comment: move hint and cursor inside your edittext up. therefore some of the text you enter into the edittext may be obscured

Comment: super great! Thanks! also I need android:gravity="bottom" in EidtText

Comment: @SooChunJung that gravity bottom fixed my issue thanks!

Comment: I tried this and found that it's better to set the paddingBottom to the RelativeLayout or ScrollView (whichever you're using), as adding the paddingBottom to the EditText itself can cause design issues with the typical line underneath the input field (in most designs) being pushed down.

Comment: paddingBottom make the editText bigger, but does not add more space between the softkeyabord and the editText

Comment: This solution not worked if you have some added some design in editText background.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work, though has some unwanted effect on the layout.

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

If anybody knows how to get this working with ADJUST_PAN, that would be great!

Comment: Does this work with full screen mode ? Because my app is in full screen. This works fine without full screen...

Comment: Not too sure about that, may be others could chip in their experiences.

Comment: ADJUST_RESIZE will not work with full screen. Not sure about PAN but probably the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add your `RelativeLayout` in `ScrollView`, and then add code below:

```
editTextField.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (hasFocus)
             scrollView.scrollBy(0, 150);

    });
```

Comment: Thanks! If you have `RecyclerView` inside `NestedScrollView`, also scroll `NestedScrollView`, not `RecyclerView`. Also probably add a short delay after a keyboard appears with `postDelayed`. `RelativeLayout`  is not required.

Comment: This code not worked on my side

Comment: if you call  scrollView.scrollBy(0, 150);  after 300 ms, it work

Answer (score 1):

The [Vasily Kabunov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47695860/5064470) answer works for me but his answer need a little change for working. The next code is:

```
editTextField.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (hasFocus) {
                Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
                    //Take care with this line I think that the scroll moves in px and not with dp.
                    scrollView.scrollBy(0, 80)
                }, 100) //You need to play with the time if your activity comes from onCreate and onResume you need to change this value to 1000.
            }

    });
}
```

And you need to add in your ScrollView or RecyclerView the next lines:

```
android:paddingBottom="80dp"
android:clipToPadding="false"
```

**IMPORTANT**: If you have activated fullscreen the flags adjustResize and adjustPan don't work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem by adding just two lines

Add this line in `EditText` -

```
android:imeOptions="actionSend|flagNoEnterAction"
```

and this line in Manifeast file in `Activity` tag add -

```
<activity
            android:name="----"
            android:icon="---"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="-----" />
```

and remove all code that you use to do this like `onTouchListner` and it should work.

Answer (score -1):

Adding `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to the activity in manifest should solve the issue. 
And this won't work if your activity is running in fullscreen. So in that case, instead of making it fullscreen via code, just add or change the style `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">` to style.xml and use this as your AppTheme. adjustResize or adjustPan both will work.