# How to put Margin between Edittext and softkeyboard in full screen

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, android-fullscreen

I am using viewpager with full screen theme.
but facing a problem that my softkeyboard hides the button when edittext in focus.

want to put some margin between EditText and Softkeyboard.

Tried all the things but nothing worked.

Please help me.

[How to add margin between EditText and Soft Keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441372/how-place-space-between-edittext-and-soft-keyboard)

this is the questions link which i've asked.

Answer (score 0):

In the activity entry in your `AndroidManifest` try putting:

`android:windowSoftInputMode:adjustPan`, this means when the keyboard comes up  it will adjust the view behind it to move up so it is not obscured by the keyboard.

In the `EditText` you can also try adding a `paddingBottom` to adjust the gap between the keyboard and the bottom of the `EditText`.

In my case I had a custom `background` for the `EditText`, which was no longer looking OK. Because the parent view for me was `ConstraintLayout` I added another `View` element behind the `EditText` with:

```
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/view_chat_history_send_text"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/view_chat_history_send_text"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/view_chat_history_send_text"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_normal"
```

Note: here `view_chat_history_send_text` is the `EditText`. And then I added a `layout_marginBottom` of the same margin as the `paddingBottom` of the `EditText`.

This means, when the `EditText` grows the background view grows as well, but it still maintains the gap between the keyboard and the `EditText` bottom.

Answer (score -1):

I applied above methods which worked for me was 
Set `android:windowSoftInputMode` on the Activity to `"adjustPan"`
than I added the padding to the edittext with gravity bottom
and it works like charm.

Comment: could you exactly tell/show what you have done? I have padding on the edittext as well, adjustPan on the activity and gravity="bottom" on the edittext as well - not working...