# Xamarin forms: How to increase the distance between keyboard and editor

Tags: xamarin.forms, editor, soft-keyboard

I need to increase the distance between the soft-keyboard and the editor in the UI. Currently, the keyboard overlaps the editor bottom part.

Screenshot adding below:

[image]

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code it will be help you.

In Xamarin Android Project

```
    public class MainActivity 
    {
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {

      Window.SetSoftInputMode(Android.Views.SoftInput.AdjustUnspecified);
     }
}
```

or in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".myActivity"
 android:label="@string/app_name"
 android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```

check the java code on given link- [KeyboardSize](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#wsoft)

Comment: I will try this and update you. I need this feature for ios also, is there solution for ios part?

Comment: In IOS it will be not giving a same layout. If you are facing same issues in IOS check the this link -https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/30336/popup-keyboard-hides-parts-of-the-ui-rather-than-resizing

Comment: I tried your code on the android part, but no change in the gap between keyboard and editor, still they are touching.

Answer (score 0):

> Xamarin forms: How to increase the distance between keyboard and editor

You could implement this feature by add [paddingBottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441372/how-to-add-margin-between-edittext-and-soft-keyboard/31135733) property for your `Edior`.

Here is an example, add the `paddingBottom` property in your `EditorRenderer`:

```
public class CustomEditorRenderer : EditorRenderer
{
    public CustomEditorRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Editor> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control == null)

            return;

        //Control.Background = new ColorDrawable(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
        //Control.Background = null;

        float scale = Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density;
        int dpAsPixels = (int)(50 * scale + 0.5f);
        Control.SetPadding(0, 0, 0, dpAsPixels);
    }
}
```

Effect: [Original space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zcPa.png), [Custom space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTWBe.png).

Comment: What will be the changes in XAML and PCL? Is this render for android or ios?

Comment: @SreejithSree, only need to create a renderer, and this is a render for android.

Comment: Android part is working fine, can you provide the renderer for IOS? sorry for the late response.

Comment: @SreejithSree, I have updated my answer, please check it.

Comment: Hi I have added the solutions after applying your solution, can you please check

Comment: @SreejithSree, the issue only happened on `iOS` platform?

Comment: @SreejithSree, would  you mind create a new ticket about this `iOS` custom space issue?

Comment: On where I need to open the ticket?

Comment: @SreejithSree,create it in StackOverFlow, we will be there to help you. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184674/discussion-between-sreejith-sree-and-york-shen-msft).